# Is AutoCorrect exposed in JavaScript API for Office or Word javaScript API?

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I'm looking for the same type of access to AutoCorrect entries as in the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word PIA; I cannot find any reference to AutoCorrect in either of these APIs used for Office Add-ins. Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't JavaScript APIs for that yet. But it's a good idea. Please go to [Office Developer Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) and request it.